# Is it possible to do for loop backward?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, for-loop

I found it not correct to do this in Objective C. So anything wrong here?

```
for (int i=10; i<=0; i--)
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The condition you've specified is wrong, following is the correct one.

```
for (int i=10; i>=0; i--)
```

Comment: @bragboy so i ran into this problem as well, and was wondering if there is a specific reason that i ==0 doesn't suffice?

Comment: @trdavidson `i==0` would not be enough because during each iteration the condition `i>=0` is evaluated and if you do `i==0` after the first iteration it would fail and terminate the loop.

Answer (score 3):

As others have noted, you want `i >= 0`. Also note that if you're iterating through 10 items, i should start at 9, not 10.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want

```
for (int i=10; i>=0; i--)
```

Comment: right, i thought it could be objc's problem, i always blame others, never thought that it's probably my own mistake