# Star Pattern Logic

Tags: objective-c, arrays

I want make a star pattern just like this.

```
    *
  * * *
* * * * *
  * * *
    *
```

I am using this code.

```
for (int i=1; i<=3; i++) {
        for (int j=1; j<=3-i; j++) {
            printf(" ");
        }
        for (int k=1; k<=2*i-1; k++) {
            printf("x");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
```

This will give

```
     *
   * * *
 * * * * *
```

How I will iterate in decrement order.

```
 when I am using 
for (int i=3; i>=0; i--) {
        for (int j=1; j<=3-i; j++) {
            printf(" ");
        }
        for (int k=1; k<=2*i-1; k++) {
            printf("x");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

xxxxx
 xxx
  x
```

How we merged it?

Comment: Use `i--` instead of `i++`

Comment: Use `>=` instead of `<=`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to do for loop backward?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3263207/is-it-possible-to-do-for-loop-backward)

Comment: What is `it`? Be clear

Comment: I am posted edit question Dear

Comment: start at 2 instead of 3. And don't call me dear please

Comment: How we merge. Please Can u share full code .

Comment: Please Accept my answer Priyanka gautam

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another logic here

```
int x=11;
int y=x/2;
int z=1;

BOOL b1=true;
BOOL b2= true;
for(int i=0;i<x;i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<y;j++)
    {
        printf(" ");
    }
    for(int k=0;k<z;k++)
    {
        printf("*");
    }
    if(y==0) b1=false;
    if(z==x) b2=false;

    y=b1?y-1:y+1;
    z=b2?z+2:z-2;
    printf("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try with below logic,

```
        for (int i=1; i<=3; i++) {
        for (int j=1; j<=3-i; j++) {
            printf(" ");
        }
        for (int k=1; k<=2*i-1; k++) {
            printf("*");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    for (int i =2; i>=0; i--) {
        for (int j=1; j<=3-i; j++) {
            printf(" ");
        }
        for (int k=1; k<=2*i-1; k++) {
            printf("*");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
```

Output Will look like :

```
  *
 ***
*****
 ***
  *
```

Answer (score 0):

The given pattern is a combination of simple pyramid star pattern and inverted pyramid star pattern. It consist of **N*2-1** rows (for this case N=3). Each row contain spaces and stars in printed in increasing and decreasing order.

Stars are printed in increasing order till **Nth row**. After Nth row stars are printed in decreasing order.

Spaces are printed in decreasing order till Nth row. After Nth row spaces are printed in increasing order. Point your mouse cursor over the pattern to count total spaces.

Step by step descriptive logic to print diamond star pattern.

1. Input number of rows to print from user (in real number of rows/2). Store it in a variable say `rows`.
2. Declare two variables to keep track of total columns to print each row, say `stars=1` and `spaces=N-1`.
3. To iterate through rows, run an outer loop from 1 to `rows*2-1`. The loop structure should look like `for(i=1; i<rows*2; i++)`.
4. To print spaces, run an inner loop from 1 to spaces. The loop structure should look like `for(j=1; j<=spaces; j++)`. Inside this loop print single space.
5. To print stars, run another inner loop from `1 to stars*2-1`. The loop structure should look like `for(j=1; j<=stars; j++)`. Inside this loop print star.
6. After printing all columns of a row, move to next line i.e. print new line.
7. Check `if(i < rows)` then increment stars and decrement spaces. Otherwise increment spaces and decrement stars.

Try Below code:-

```
    int i, j, rows;
    int stars, spaces;

    printf("Enter rows to print : ");
    scanf("%d", &rows);

    stars = 1;
    spaces = rows - 1;

     /* Iterate through rows */
    for(i=1; i<rows*2; i++)
    {
    /* Print spaces */
    for(j=1; j<=spaces; j++)
        printf(" ");

    /* Print stars */
    for(j=1; j<stars*2; j++)
        printf("*");

    /* Move to next line */
    printf("\n");

    if(i<rows)
    {
        spaces--;
        stars++;
    }
    else
    {
        spaces++;
        stars--;
    }
    }
```